# twitter authentication while playing games in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, twitter

I am currently creating a browser-based game with html5 and javascript. During the game, if an user loses, he/she has to tweet in order to continue to play the game(I know how cunning this specification sounds like, but my boss told me to implement this). Although I know how to authenticate an user using PHP and ajax, I am not sure how to make sure that the user indeed tweeted. What is the best way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter does not return if they tweeted so the user has choice, my recommendation would be to make them tweet a specific text that you can then search for to see if they tweeted. However the catch is not all tweets are indexed in the search so some players may become angry if they do tweet and it doesn't work, however it should work.

Documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

You will need to make an authenticated request to:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=[username]
```

Comment: So you mean that each post has to have a unique text so that my app can be sure an user really tweeted?

Comment: Yes, how ever this works on the basis that you know the users Twitter Username, if you don't know it you will just have to do a generic search for a string which is less likely to find the tweet, I recommend you make them login, with twitter store their details then when they tweet check for the tweet.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope twitter will implement the feature someday even though I think not so many people will appreciate it.